# Discord.js - How to make a function only run every 30 seconds

Tags: discord.js

I made a bot that replies to a user's message but I want to limit it so that the bot only responds every 30 seconds and ignores the messages within that time. Do I use SetInterval?

Code:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  main();
}, 30000);

function main(){
      ***command here***
}
```

This isn't working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use `setInterval()` for that.

However, I suggest using [`client.setInterval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=setInterval) and [`client.setTimeout()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=setTimeout) instead of just `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` because according to the docs:

> Sets an interval that will be automatically cancelled if the client is destroyed.

Which means that if you restart or stop your bot those timers would be cleared.

```js
client.setInterval(function() {
  main();
}, 30000);
```